# Pulling All Remote Branches Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

I am writing a project in xcode with a team and we use git for version control. Xcode has a bunch of really nice built in features for git and one of the is the pull option. This is great but I would like to have xcode pull all the remote branches so that I do not have to pull them one by one. Is there an easy way to do this or will I be forced to the command line every time I wish to pull all branches.

Thanks.